# Hard disk solution

Tags: disk, shortcuts

I am using Kubuntu.

As shown above I have a 7.3tb partition at `sda1` labeled E.
The entry into fstab reads:  `/dev/sda1 /mnt/E ext4 defaults 0 0`

```
sda      8:0    0   7.3T  0 disk
└─sda1   8:1    0   7.3T  0 part /mnt/E
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb2   8:18   0   931G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                 /snap
                                 /
sdc      8:32   0   3.6T  0 disk
└─sdc1   8:33   0   3.6T  0 part /home/seth/4TBSSD
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

How do I get said partition to show in the Dolphin File Manager root directory as a folder called "E".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you see now? Does it not appear? Does it appear with a different name?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Dolphin (I also don't know what "Dolphin File Manager root directory" means), but you can change the mountpoint in `fstab` to mount the disk in the root directory (`/`).

First create the new directory:

```
sudo mkdir /E
```

Then edit your `fstab` to mount in a new location:

```
/dev/sda1 /E ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Finally reboot to spin up at the new mountpoint.

This method works no matter where you want to mount the disk, just replace `/E` in both commands with the exact directory where you want to mount the disk.

Comment: I don't use graphical file managers, but from what little experience of them I have, they show the directory name, not the full path. So both something mounted at `/mnt/E` and something mounted at `/E` should be shown as `E` in the manager. So this shouldn't change anything for the OP and it is not really a good idea to mount things directly under `/` for no reason.

Comment: Then I think the OP should explain what they would like to do ..

Answer (score 0):

A way to have `E` show up in the root of your system, without actually moving stuff, is to create a symbolic link to it:

```
sudo ln -s /mnt/E /E
```

However, that remains an unusual place for a mounted partition to show up. Your home directory would be a better choice.